# Mysql group by query optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have query like this in mysql

```
select count(*) 
from (
    select count(idCustomer)
    from customer_details 
    where ... 
    group by idCustomer having max(trx_staus) = -1 
) as temp
```

So basically finding customer count that fulfill certain where condition (one or two) with max transaction state  = -1 (other can be 2,3,4). but this query takes about 30 min on my local machine and 13 sec on high configuration server (about 20 gb ram and 8 core processor). i have  13 lac rows in table. i know group by and having max function are too costly. what can i do to optimize this query. any suggestion?

Comment: Anything other than simple conditions in the `WHERE ...`?

Comment: no, nothing, and where condition is so simple, and some time not used, in above case i have not used, but it my required some time that is why i have mentioned.

Comment: Are all the fields in WHERE, GROUP BY and MAX clause(s) indexed accordingly?

Comment: yes, all required fields are indexed

Answer (score 0):

The inner query has to inspect *all* rows to determine the aggregate maximum; if you want to optimize this, add a calculated field that contains the maximum to your customer table and select on that.

The trick is then to keep that field up-to-date :)

Comment: you said it can only be -1, 2, 3 and 4 no?

Comment: it was about transaction state in max() function

Comment: @Nirmal-thInkbeYond I meant to keep the max() in a calculated field, so I'm not sure how that wouldn't work for you.